# AlarmManager after task killed

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

```
SilenceReceiver silenceReceiver = new SilenceReceiver();
IntentFilter silenceFilter = new IntentFilter(SilenceReceiver.SILENCE_ALARM);
registerReceiver(silenceReceiver, silenceFilter);

AwakeReceiver awakeReceiver = new AwakeReceiver();
IntentFilter awakeFilter = new IntentFilter(AwakeReceiver.WAKE_ALARM);
registerReceiver(awakeReceiver, awakeFilter);

GregorianCalendar sleepCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
sleepCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, sleepCalendar.get(Calendar.SECOND)+5);
long triggerTime = sleepCalendar.getTimeInMillis();

GregorianCalendar awakeCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
awakeCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, awakeCalendar.get(Calendar.SECOND)+30);
long awakeTime = awakeCalendar.getTimeInMillis();

AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Service.ALARM_SERVICE);
PendingIntent sleepIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new   Intent(SilenceReceiver.SILENCE_ALARM), 0);
alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerTime, sleepIntent);
PendingIntent awakeIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(AwakeReceiver.WAKE_ALARM), 0);
alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, awakeTime, awakeIntent);
```

The problem is if the task is killed my AwakeReceiver never gets trigger. Is there anything I can do about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register the intent filters for the broadcast receiver in the manifest instead of in code.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to do it in code so that I can dynamically register/unregister them? Or does having registered receivers that go unused not tax the battery?

Comment: Why does it differ? (I know it does but why/how?) Is there another context when registered in manifest? And why is it not possible to unregister in code if you registered in the manifest?
And more importantly what can you do if you have to register for an action like ACTION_SCREEN_OFF where it has to be done in code? How can you register it to behave like if it was registered in the manifest?